# Warum sagt man "Barkeeper", obwohl es ungebräuchlich im Englischen ist?

Tags: anglicism, pseudo-anglicism

Wie man [hier](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/194265/barkeeper-or-bartender-how-to-address-them) lesen kann, ist die Bezeichnung "barkeeper" im British English fast völlig unbenutzt.
Anhand meiner eigenen Erfahrung kann ich auch nur sagen, dass "bartender" **viel** öfter verwendet wird. Ich habe "barkeeper" noch nie im Englischen Verwendung finden sehen. Das gilt auch für American English.

Im Deutschen sagt man aber standardmäßig ["Barkeeper/in" oder "Barmann"](http://www.duden.de/suchen/dudenonline/barkeeper).

Warum ist das so?
Hat man früher "Barhälter" oder "Thekenhälter" gesagt oder was?

Comment: Solche Scheinanglizismen gibt es massenhaft. Siehe auch https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scheinanglizismus

Comment: Ähnlich... Warum "keeper" statt "goalie"?

Comment: Genaueres weiß ich nicht, aber den Begriff gibt es im Englischen durchaus: http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/barkeeper?q=barkeep Mir scheint das also eher auf dem Niveau von „Friseur“ zu sein: Hat man in der Ursprungssprache vielleicht mal gesagt, ist im Moment aber nicht der gebräuchliche Begriff.

Comment: Bei kleinen Bars ist meistens der Besitzer auch der Mann hinter der Theke.

Comment: Im Englischen war der Begriff [zwischen 1890 und 1920 weit verbreitet](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=barkeeper&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3). Im Deutschen scheint die Verwendung allerdings [erst 1980](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=barkeeper&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=20&smoothing=3) zuzunehmen.

Comment: Naja, warum sagt man so Sachen wie "Handy" (was jetzt im Englischen aus dem "Denglischen" übernommen wird)? Oder "Body Bag" (was im Englischen was ganz anderes heißt)? Oder Smoking (was es im Englischen gar nicht gibt)?

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar Mit dem Unterschied, dass es "barkeeper" im Englischen wirklich gibt und die gleiche Bedeutung hat. Die Frage ist, warum solch ein Anglizismus benutzt wird, obwohl er im Englischen nicht/selten benutzt wird. Oder sehe ich das falsch?

Comment: Ich würde einfach sagen, dass es der amerikanische Ausdruck ist. _Bar_ ist ja auch eher was amerikanisches. _Pubs_ dagegen eher britisch/irisch.

Comment: Barkeeper is quite common in America, very occasionally abbreviated to barkeep. In the UK traditionally there are pubs and not bars, so publican or pub keeper is customary.

Comment: @Vogel612 Sowohl *keeper* als *goalie* sind auf Englisch gängig, soweit ich weiß sogar beiderseits des Teichchens.

Comment: Die Vorstellung, ein einmal aus einer Fremdsprache entlehnter und etablierter Begriff würde synchron zu dieser Vorlage gepflegt und angepasst, erscheint mir ziemlich idealistisch und von tatsächlicher Sprachentwicklung weit entfernt.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Es stimmt, dass *barkeeper* und *barman* heutzutage nicht so üblich sind in den englischsprachigen Ländern.  Im größten solchen Land hört man heute vor allem *bartender*.

[image]

Aber früher, zur Zeit der Entlehnung in viele europäischen Sprachen, war das anders.  Die Antwort ist also schlicht:

## Die englische Sprache hat sich geändert.

Enge Verwandte von unsrem *Barmann* gibt es auf Russisch (*бармен*), Türkisch (*barmen*) und so weiter.

Insofern ist *Barmann* kein Scheinanglizismus, was nicht garantiert, dass es bei modernen Englischsprechern weltweit als richtig oder überhaupt bekannt empfunden wird.

Das ist jetzt alles mehr oder weniger abgesehen davon dass einige Sinne von *bar* (z.B. Kneipe) in vielen wichtigen Varianten des Englischen mit *pub* konkurrieren.

Darüber hinaus ist gerade *Barkeeper* der Aufsteiger in den letzten Jahrzehnten.

[image]

Ich kenne keine Erklärung dafür, vermute ganz grob Englischwahn plus Netzwerkeffekt.

Es würde mich auch interessieren, was es ersetzt hat.  *Wirt* ging nach dem Krieg unter, hat aber viele anderen Bedeutungen.

[image]

Statistische Vergleiche ohne Zusammenhang bringen also nur so viel, denn die Kulturen inklusive Saufkulturen haben sich im selben Zeitraum sehr geändert.

Comment: Ich verstehe den letzten Satz nicht. Ist „nur so viel“ hier vielleicht ein Anglizismus?

Comment: Bei mir herrscht ein deutsch-englisch-serbokroatisches-russisch-armenisches Durcheinander, alle Theorien sind möglich. :-)  Also Du sag mir halt, was schreibt man wenn weder *bringen nicht viel* noch *bringen viel* stimmt?  *bringen nur einiges* klingt auch nicht so fein.

Comment: Verstehe. Das Problem ist, dass meine erste Lesweise des Satzes ist, dass sie viel bringen. In dieser Lesweise bezieht sich das *nur* auf das *weil*: Nur weil die Kulturen sich sehr geändert haben, bringen statistische Vergleiche so viel. Das ergibt nur inhaltlich wenig Sinn. Wie es besser geht? Hmm, vielleicht "haben begrenzte Aussagekraft"? Etwas sperrig, ich weiß...

Comment: Ich will halt dass man die Ziffern kritisch betrachtet, im gesellschaftlichen Zusammenhang.

Comment: zB [*Wein*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Wein&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=20&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CWein%3B%2Cc0) steigt ab während [die spezifischen Sorten](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Merlot%2CShiraz%2CSauvignon+Blanc%2CRos%C3%A9%2C+Syrah&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=20&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CMerlot%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CShiraz%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CSauvignon%20Blanc%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CRos%C3%A9%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CSyrah%3B%2Cc0) viel öfter erwähnt werden.  Einkommen, Weltanschauung, Glaube, vieles hat sich geändert.

Comment: +1 insbesonder für die Erwähnung der Entlenhungen ins Russiche und Türkische.

Comment: Mit der Aussagekraft der letzten Ngram-Grafik zum Begriff "wirt" sollte man aufpassen, da dort wohl nicht nur der "Wirt" reinspielt, sondern auch viele "wirt"-Schreibweisen, die nun "wird" geschrieben werden. Mit größerem Smoothing lässt sich ein Abfall des Wirts auch erst ab ca 1960 erkennen. [Link zum Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Wirt&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=20&smoothing=50&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2CWirt%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3BWirt%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bwirt%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: Danke, das ist problematisch.  Die Lösung ist aber nicht *smoothing* aufzudrehen, sondern *case-insensitive* anzukreuzen, was ja wieder zum ursprünglichen Schluss zurückführt, oder es mit einem n-Gram wie *der Wirt* oder *vom Wirt* zu probieren.

Answer (score -1):

*Barkeeper* ist im Deutschen die geläufigere Bezeichnung, *Barmann* ist zwar ebenso richtig, aber seltener benutzt wegen der Tatsache, dass es kein feminines Gegenstück gibt. Denn unter einer *Bardame* versteht man eine [Animierdame](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Animierdame)

**Büffetkellner** ist wohl ein älterer, deutscher Begriff, der verwendet wurde, bevor sich Barkeeper eingebürgert hat. Dieser Scheinanglizismus kommt wahrscheinlich daher, dass die "Barkeeper"-Szene zuerst eine Untergrund-Szene in den USA war, während der Zeit der Alkohol-Prohibition. Dieser Trend schwappte (wie so viele andere auch) nach Deutschland über, sodass sich dieser Begriff einfach eingebürgert hat über die Jahre.

Comment: Die Prohibition ist wohl kaum als Trend nach Deutschland geschwappt. :)

Comment: -1 Wie wäre es mit Barfrau als weibliches Gegenstück zu Barmann? Wiki scheint den Begriff ja nicht zu kennen, mit Google findet man aber eine Menge Jobangebote dafür. Deine Antwort besteht nur aus Vermutungen die du Dir irgendwie zusammenreimst.

Comment: @userunknown Es ist wohl logisch, dass der Trend der Barkeeper-Szenen gemeint ist und nicht der Trend der Prohibition. Immerhin wird dies nur im Nebensatz erwähnt.

Comment: Barkeeperszenen können ein Trend sein? Das wusste ich nicht.

Comment: Ich glaube der Smiley am Ende von @userunknown Kommentar soll Ironie ausdrücken (korrigier' mich falls nicht). Davon abgesehen ist deine Antwort ganz interessant aber geht meiner Meinung nach nicht wirklich auf meine Frage ein.

Comment: "Büffet" klingt mir jetzt aber nicht übermäßig deutsch... :)